# Capture iPhone/iPad number of pages

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to understand if is it's possible to capture into my code the number of pages an iPhone/iPad has.... I'm referring to the pages created by the user as more apps are installed on the device... Cheers!

Comment: number of pages of *what*?  the number of apps?

Comment: He's asking for the # of pages that hold the apps

Comment: Yep. # of pages on the iPhone home dash board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean the number of pages on the iphone home dash board, then no, you will not be able to query that information legally

Comment: This is what I thought... Cheers!